# Unable to run `@reboot` crontab at reboot

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, linux, cron

I am trying to run two Python programs at reboot with my Raspberry Pi 3. The problem is that crontab doesn't run at reboot.

I tried to run the programs with crontab every 5 minutes and everything went correct.

This is working:

```
*/5 * * * * python /home/pi/Desktop/Telegram/pyTelegramBotAPI/ComandosRes.py
*/5 * * * * sudo python /home/pi/Desktop/Telegram/pyTelegramBotAPI/Correo+.py
```

This is **not** working:

```
@reboot sudo python /home/pi/Desktop/Telegram/pyTelegramBotAPI/Correo+.py
@reboot python /home/pi/Desktop/Telegram/pyTelegramBotAPI/ComandosRes.py
```

Any idea or suggestion is welcomed. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since we don't know the script content, it's not clear if this matters, but you list the programs in a different order between the two cases. Does one depend on the other? (If so, you should make a better fix than *just* the order here, but the order might matter.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Debian stretch manpage for cron](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/systemd-cron/crontab.5.en.html) notes the following:

> Please note that startup, as far as @reboot is concerned, may be
>   before some system daemons, or other facilities, were startup. This is
>   due to the boot order sequence of the machine.

You could try adding a sleep duration to the start of your script, or possibly launching it later in the boot process using `systemd`. Here's an example of a service file I've used to launch after networking is up and running, and with a 10 second safety buffer:

1. Create `/etc/systemd/system/yourname.service` containing:

   ```
   [Install]
   WantedBy=multi-user.target

   [Unit]
   Description=Example service
   Wants=network-online.target
   After=network-online.target

   [Service]
   User=youruser
   Group=yourgroup
   ExecStart=/path/to/your/script.py
   ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 10
   Type=simple

   [Timer]
   OnStartupSec=25
   ```
2. Enable the service with `systemctl enable yourname`.
3. Start the service with `systemctl start yourname`.
4. Verify proper startup with `systemctl status yourname`.

There is a lot more to systemd, but hopefully this will get you started. Note that this completely replaces the `cron @reboot` and/or `/etc/rc.local` approaches which don't provide as much control over when services are launched.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I will try it tomorrow and I will comment something. Thanks again.

Comment: @Andermutu I just went through something similar. The problem was a script launching before the network was fully ready at reboot. I wound up fixing it by adding "ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 10" to the .service file I installed via systemd. For some reason, "After=network-online.target" was not sufficient. You might add some network-readiness checks to your script rather than just adding delays. To do this "properly", you might want to read up on systemd rather than cron.

Comment: Thanks again for your help bobstro. This days I have very little time to try it. As soon as I have time I will try it and I will accept your answer and give you positive mark. Thanks!

Comment: Hello Bobstro; I am trying to implement your solution but I dont understand exactly were I have to add "ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 10". Do I have to add it in my Crontab file, Pyhton file or do I have to create a file in systemd?Thanks and sorry, I am a begginer.

Comment: Better is to determine where in the startup process you want your program to launch and use `Wants=` and `After=` lines. If you find that you still have problems, you can insert a short delay with `ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 10` under the `[Service]` block. I'll edit my answer to include more detail.

Comment: Sorry for updating again, but I have got problems again. In my system.sh i get this error while checking the status of the process root.service: Failed at step USER spawning /bin/sleep: No such process. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: How long of a sleep interval did you specify? It will time out if it's too long.